# Need help getting adult to show value inputted by the user output always displays zero for some reason

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const float DESSERT_PRICE = 4.50;
const float TAX_RATE = 0.07;
const float GRATUITY = 0.15;
const float COST_ADULT = 12.75;
const float COST_CHILD = 7.65;
const float COST_DESERT = 3.00;

int readinput(string, int, int, int, float, float);
float mult_args(float, float);
float add_args(float,float);

int main()
{ 
    string name;
    int Adult, Child, Dessert;
    float Room_Fee, Deposit;
    float Adult_Cost,Child_Cost, Desert_Cost, 
      Food_Cost,Tips,Taxes,Total_Bill,Balance;
    name = readinput(name,Adult,Child,Dessert,Room_Fee,Deposit);

    Adult_Cost = mult_args(COST_ADULT, Adult);
    cout << Adult_Cost;


}

int readinput(string name, int Adult, int Child, int Dessert, float      Room_Fee, float Deposit)
{
cout << "\t\t\tCustomers Name : ";getline(cin,name);
cout << "\t\t\t Number of Adults : ";cin>>Adult;
cout << "\t\t\t Number of Children  : ";cin >> Child;
cout << "\t\t    Number of Desserts : ";cin >> Dessert;
cout << "\t\t\t Room Fee : ";cin >> Room_Fee;
cout << "\t\t\t Deposit: ";cin >> Deposit;


}

float mult_args(float left, float right)
{
    return left * right;
}

float add_args(float left,float right)
{
    return left + right;    
}
```

the problem is the print of the cost of adult total only displays zero need       it to display the cost per adult times the input value in the fucntion read input hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhelp

Comment: You are not returning any values from `readinput` function

Comment: You are passing copies of the variables to the function, not the actual variables.  Try passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readInput` function is using *copies* of the variables passed to it:

```
int readinput(string name, int Adult, int Child, int Dessert, float      Room_Fee, float Deposit)
```

I recommend passing by reference so you can modify the variables that were passed:

```
int readinput(string& name, int& Adult, int& Child, int& Dessert, float&      Room_Fee, float& Deposit)
```

Another issue is that you state in the declaration that the function returns an `int` but there is not a `return` statement in the code for the function.  Functions do not have to return a value.  You can declare them as returning `void` instead.

Also, set the compiler's warning level to maximum.  The compiler should let you know that the variables were "set but not used", which let's you know something is wrong and to review your code.